# Netbeans: how to tell what JAR am I currently looking at

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, netbeans-8

Working on Netbeans you can CTRL+click symbols and that will take you to the code that defines such symbol. When there is no code available because the symbol is in a JAR, a message "Showing generated source file. No sources are attached to class 'Jar file" is shown with some source code with the function definitions.

Is there any way to tell which JAR is the code actually being pulled from?

I have inherited a project with dozens of similarly named JARs without source. Identifying the name of the JAR would point me to the repo where the sources are and I could attach them. Eclipse-based IDEs have a very handy button in the project explorer "Link with Editor" but I can't find anything similar in Netbeans.

This is what I see:

[image: example]

This is what I am looking for:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View->Synchronize Editor With Views

The project explorer will then switch to the file currently open.

Comment: Thanks! That was actually the first thing I tried but I had the Files tab open and it did not work. Then I noticed it works in the Projects tab.

Comment: @JosepValls,Check this one out,  this one is completely new to me: ctrl + shift +1

Answer (score 1):

Right click, Select in Projects.

Comment: I looked through all the menus before looking at the context menu!